# Como responder a un correo en especifico desde c#

Tags: c#, email, smtp, mail, outlook

lo que pasa es que debo responder un correo en especifico, tengo el messageid y estoy utilizando smtp con una cuenta de outlook, ya puedo enviar correos nuevos con MailMessage, pero necesito contestar a un correo en especifico, les agradezco su apoyo, comparto lo que tengo hasta el momento.

```
                var correo = conversacion.Campana.CampanaCorreo.FirstOrDefault();

                System.Net.Mail.MailMessage Correo = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                Correo.To.Add(new MailAddress(conversacion.Comodin8));
                Correo.From = new MailAddress(correo.Correo);
                Correo.Subject = "Respuesta de "+ conversacion.Campana.Nombre;
                Correo.Body = cuerpo;
                Correo.IsBodyHtml = true;
                Correo.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.Normal;

                var smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(correo.Correo, correo.Password);
                smtp.Host = correo.Host;
                smtp.Port = Convert.ToInt32(correo.Port);
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;


                try
                {
                    smtp.Send(Correo);
                    smtp.Dispose();
                    Console.WriteLine("Correo enviado satisfactoriamente");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error al eviar al correo: " + ex.Message.ToString());
                }
```

Comment: ¿qué parámetros tiene el correo específico que debes de contestar? ¿algún asunto específico? ¿de algún remitente en especial?

Answer (score 0):

finalmente lo resolví enviando en el asunto exactamente el mismo del correo que deseo responder y le agregue los Headers:

```
                MailMessage Correo = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                Correo.Headers.Add("In-Reply-To", "<message-id>");
                Correo.Headers.Add("References", "<message-id>");
```

Reemplace el  por el del correo que quiero responder.